# computing $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} ) / \langle(3,6),(5,5)\rangle$, quotient by two generators.

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

I want to compute following things $(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} ) / \langle(3,6),(5,5)\rangle$

First of all, I know for one generator case 
$(\mathbb{Z} \oplus \mathbb{Z} ) / \langle(m,n)\rangle \cong \mathbb{Z}$

If $gcd(m,n)=1$ and for $gcd(m,n)=d$, it reduces $\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_d$

What I want to do next is generalized this case to two generators. 
Is there any ideas for computing this kinds of things?

Comment: Yes you apply the Smith Normal Form algorithm,.

Comment: You could use that $R/(a, b)\cong (R/(a))/(\bar b)$ where $\bar b$ is the image of $b$ in $R/(a)$.

Comment: You might be interested in the structure theorem of modules over principal ideal domains (PID's). The Smith Normal Form algorithm can be used to prove this theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 
$$\begin{aligned}
\langle (3,6),(5,5)\rangle
&=\langle (5,5) -2(3,6), (3,6) \rangle = \langle (1,7),(3,6) \rangle
\\ &= \langle (1,7), (3,6)-3(1,7) \rangle = \langle (1,7), (0,15) \rangle
\end{aligned}$$

Therefore, $$(\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z})/\langle (3,6),(5,5)\rangle \cong (\mathbb{Z}\oplus \mathbb{Z}_{15})/\langle (1,\overline{7})\rangle := G$$

I put over-line on the seven to emphasis it is computed modulo 15. Now lets interpret the last group (or ring). In $G$, any $(a,b)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ equals $(0,c)\in \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}_{15}$ for some $c$. Note that $$a = (1,\overline{0}) = (0,\overline{-7})$$

You will convince yourself that $G\cong C_{15}$ after computing $2a, 3a, ..., 14a$.

---

If you know something about $\mathbb{Z}$-module, then the abelian group given has presentation matrix $\begin{pmatrix} 3 & 5 \\ 6 & 5 \end{pmatrix}$, which can be brought to $\begin{pmatrix} 5 & 0 \\ 0 & 3 \end{pmatrix}$ by some elementary column and row operation (in $\mathbb{Z}$), so $G\cong C_3\times C_5$.

Answer (score 1):

SNF on the generators matrix:
$$\begin{pmatrix}3&6\\5&5\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{L_2-2L_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\5&\!-5\end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2-\frac53R_1}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\0&\!-5\end{pmatrix}\longrightarrow\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix}$$

and you get a(n abelian) group of order

$$\;\det\begin{pmatrix}3&0\\0&5\end{pmatrix}=15\;,\;\;\text{and in fact}\;\;\Bbb Z\oplus\Bbb Z/\langle(3,6),\,(5,5)\rangle\cong\Bbb Z_3\oplus\Bbb Z_5$$